# How to replace the NSDictionary value from another value in Objective C?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have a `NSMutableArray` below like this

```
(
   {
    Realimg = "<UIImage: 0x13951b130>, {800, 600}";
    "bid_accepted" = 1;
    "bid_amount" = 100;
    "bid_amount_num" = 100;
    "bid_cur_name" = USD;
    "bid_cur_symb" = $;
    "bid_currencycode" = 4;
    "bid_date" = "05 Nov 2015";
    "bid_msg" = testing;
    "bid_user_id" = 2;
    "nego_id" = 612;
    "pas_count" = 5;
    "ride_address" = "Sample Address";
    "ride_cover_img" = "uploadfiles/UploadUserImages/2/mobile/21426739600s-end-horton-plains.jpg";
    "ride_id" = 149;
    "ride_name" = "Ride to the World's End";
    "ride_type_id" = 0;
    "ride_type_name" = Travel;
    "ride_user_fname" = Nik;
    "ride_user_id" = 2;
    "ride_user_lname" = Mike;
   }

)
```

What I want to do is, replace the  "bid_currencycode" = 4; by a different value.I want to replace 4 by 5. How can I do this? Please someone help me.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to create the array or for doing the replacement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following code for doing the same:

```
// Getting the dictionary from your array and making it to a mutable copy
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [yourArray[index] mutableCopy];

// Changing the specified key
[dict setObject:@(5) forKey:@"bid_currencycode"];

// Replacing the current dictionary with modified one
[yourArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:dict];
```

Here:

- `yourArray` is a `NSMutableArray`
- `index` is a valid index (index of object, that you need to change the value)

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below coding

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

//your array

dic =[yourArray objectAtIndex:0];

[dict removeObjectForKey:@"bid_currencycode"];

[dict setObject:@“5” forKey:@"bid_currencycode"];

[yourArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:dict];
```

0 is (yourArray index number) You can change according your array index number